# Nvidia Prime enable vsync

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

A few days ago I posted a similar [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353685/ubuntu-20-04-stuck-on-boot-screen-before-login?noredirect=1#comment2315541_1353685) where I was stuck on booting screen before login after doing some manipulation on nvidia drivers.

The reason I did this was to enable vsync in order to get rid of permanent screen tearing issues. I could find many references to similar issues on the web and most of them rely on either enabling the issue from Nvidia X Server Settings ([which I can't do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC6Rh.png)) or editing the configuration file to add the following line:

`Option  "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"`

The issue I currently face however is that the simple fact of creating the configuration file by clicking on "Save to X configuration file" causes my pc to be unable to reboot. Deleting the file in recovery mode enables me to boot again, so I guess something must be wrong with the file that breaks Xorg server.

Does anyone would have a solution in order to enable vsync, or help me fix the xconf file ?

Thanks for the help !